# Event.target.value is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, tsx

I am trying to create a timer window and I have created a seperate component for that. I am trying to pass the time in from the main component into the child component. The issue is the state for the timer input box is not changing. I have tried using `useEffect` but I have a feeling I may be implementing it wrongly.

Update
Found out that the `event.target.value` is returning an undefined which is why the state is not changing. Any ideas as to why it is returning an undefined?

Code

```
// Parent Component
  const [targetTimeS, setTargetTimeS] = React.useState(60);


 function handleMinuteSelectionChange(event) {
    const minuteSelection = event.target.value;

    if (isNaN(minuteSelection)) {
      window.alert("Please select a number");
    } else {
      const minuteSelectionS = parseInt(minuteSelection);
      if (minuteSelectionS > 59 || minuteSelectionS < 0) {
        window.alert("Please choose a minutes value between 0 and 59");
      } else {
        console.log(`Minute selection changed: ${minuteSelectionS}`);
        setTempTargetTimeS(minuteSelectionS * 60);
      }
    }
  }

  function timerWindow() {
    return (
      <TimerWindow
        handleTargetTimeCancelButtonClicked={
          handleTargetTimeCancelButtonClicked
        }
        handleMinuteSelectionChange={(e)=> handleMinuteSelectionChange(e)}
        handleTargetTimeDoneButtonClicked={handleTargetTimeDoneButtonClicked}
        value={targetTimeS / 60}
        openModal={showTargetTimeWindow}
        closeModal={hideTargetTimeWindow}
        handlePresetButtonClicked={handlePresetButtonClicked}
        handleHideTimerWindowClicked={hideTargetTimeWindow}
      />
    );
  }
```

```
Child Component
export default function TimerWindow(props: {
  handleTargetTimeDoneButtonClicked: (e) => void;
  handleTargetTimeCancelButtonClicked: (e) => void;
  handleMinuteSelectionChange: (e) => void;
  handlePresetButtonClicked?: (e: number) => void;
  handleHideTimerWindowClicked?: (e) => void;
  closeModal: (e) => void;
  openModal: boolean;
  value: number;
}): JSX.Element {
  const [targetTimeS, setTargetTimeS] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTargetTimeS(props.value);
    console.log(props.value);
  }, [targetTimeS]);

  const recorderClasses = speechRecorderStyles();

  return (
    <Modal open={props.openModal} onClose={props.closeModal}>
      <div className={recorderClasses.targetTimeWindow}>
        <CloseIcon
          onClick={props.handleHideTimerWindowClicked}
          className={recorderClasses.windowCloseButton}
        />
        <Typography className={recorderClasses.selectRecordingTime}>
          Select recording time
        </Typography>
        <Stack spacing={4} direction="column" alignItems="center" height="100%">
          <Stack spacing={4} direction="row">
            <TimerPresets onClick={props.handlePresetButtonClicked} />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>

        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="Minutes"
          variant="outlined"
          className={recorderClasses.targetTimeSelection}
          value={targetTimeS}
          onChange={(e) => props.handleMinuteSelectionChange(e.target.value)}
          sx={{
            mt: 6,
            ml: 1,
          }}
          type="number"
        />
        <Stack spacing={4} direction="row">
          <Button
            className={recorderClasses.targetTimeCancelButton}
            onClick={props.handleTargetTimeCancelButtonClicked}
          >
            <Typography
              className={recorderClasses.targetTimeCancelButtonTypography}
            >
              Cancel
            </Typography>
          </Button>
          <Button
            className={recorderClasses.targetTimeDoneButton}
            onClick={props.handleTargetTimeDoneButtonClicked}
          >
            <Typography
              className={recorderClasses.targetTimeDoneButtonTypography}
            >
              Done
            </Typography>
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing the equivalent of `event.target.value.target.value` because you are calling `event.target.value` twice. That`s why it is returning undefined.

The first call is in your `textField` in the `onChange` callback:

```js
onChange={(e) => props.handleMinuteSelectionChange(e.target.value)}
```

So you are already passing the value of the target component up and not the event. But then you are handling the value as it was the event in your `handleMinuteSelectionChange`

```
//Here in reality you have already the value, not the event
function handleMinuteSelectionChange(event) { 
    const minuteSelection = event.target.value;

    //remaining code ...
}
```

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense, but that doesn't explain why the state isn't updating on the inputbox

Comment: If you need to pass a state down to a child component that must only render that value you don't have to use an inner state, just use the props! Furthermore, your `useEffect` has an infinite loop "embedded" since you are updating the state every time the state itself changes. Isn't your console displaying something like "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"?